# Creating a simple shopping basket in PHP using session variables

Tags: php, html, e-commerce, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting very confused with ISSET, GET and SESSIONS, trying to create a simple shopping basket. I have a link "Add to basket", under each of my items, when clicking this I want to start a session for the cart, and add that item to the basket, so my item amount variable will increment to one and the price will start with the value of the selected item. I have a mini shopping cart at the top of the page where I want these values to update as items are selected.

I made a mess of my code and deleted it all to start again, before I do I was hoping for some advice, I have read up on carts and sessions for a week now. I have a database that contains products and information such as range, category and price etc. I also have links in the mini basket which will clear the basket and also open the basket in a web page to provide more detail.

Comment: I know it isn't what you are asking, but I've seen great success with people utilizing frameworks like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) rather than re-inventing the wheel and possibly making things very insecure and a nightmare to later update.  Take a look at [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com), it has a built in database handler, allows you to use their '[shopping cart](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html)' functionality, and above all it has great [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/)

Comment: Thanks for your input I shall look into your suggestions. I am however needing to study and understand how to build a shopping cart from the ground up. Thanks.

Comment: the problem is there is a number of ways to do it, many of which would be correct depending on your situation, from a simple cart to a complex cart.  There is no right way to do it, however going the framework route you get a deeper understanding of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use POST, not GET
assuming you have an item id in the $_POST['item'] variable:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['item'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['item'];
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I see that POST is safer than using GET, thanks for your advice!